# Hyper V Port forwarding help

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I am trying to enable some sort of port forwarding to my test hyper V clients.

Say the main server IP address is 213.112.*.*

and i want the internal Hyper V Cients to be assigned External IP addresses that I have been given with a co location, and there on a diferent subnet. example 92.112.*.*

How can i route these so that say i can RDP to 92.112.*.* and log directly onto my hyperV clients from the internet?

As at the moment they all have internal IP addresses and they have internet access but i can not RDP onto them as there is no link between the networks.

I am just learning all this so please help.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is in the network type (configured on the HyperV server) that you've connected your guests to.

So you head to HyperV management, and you'll notice you can create different networks, and select which ones each guest connects to.  Likely they're currently set to a private network, with its own private NAT.  Create a new one (I believe "bridged" is the term you want), and switch your guests to that network.

Conceptually, think of each network in HyperV as a physical switch, and you're just "plugging" in the guests. At that point, you can treat them exactly as you would any physical machine on the network.

Comment: Yes, "bridged" is the term. @Kevin, it would be unusual for someone to want to NAT any kind of a virtual server at the hypervisor level; normally one would use bridged networking in the hypervisor configuration and expect any NAT to be configured on the physical router/firewall, just as one would do with a physical server.

Answer (score 0):

So all i need to do really is add them to a external network and tey should be able to at as if they are plugged directly in to theetwork? But for people RDP'ing into them will the switch be able to route it correctly? As say the Datacenter gives you a set of 5 IP Addresses and 1 of them is in the 213.229 range sub net and then the other is in the 94.76 range.
I was told by the datacenter to after creating the hyper V box i would need to make a vm with say Ubuntu 10.4 server on it. then load Unbuntu Routing packages. and create 1 vm as a router for all other hyper V boxex so this would work? so i am a little confused on how its should be done.